# button click Textview text to android inbuilt messaging app

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext, messaging

how to set my editText text into android inbuilt messaging app compose activity.
here i am having code to jump from one activity to another, how to set my edittext text into inbuilt messaging app.

```
public class msg1Screen extends Activity {

Button simpleBtn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.msg1);  

    simpleBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    simpleBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent mgActivity = new Intent(msg1Screen.this, msgScreen.class);     
            startActivity(mgActivity);  
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send a message:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:"));        

 intent.putExtra("sms_body", yourEditTextString);
 startActivity(intent);
```

To add a phone number :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + phoneNumber));
```

Comment: thank u issathink, your code Almost working but not getting text from edittext. I made some changes as i dont need any phone number in It.                                                                                                                                                                                                               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" ));        

 intent.putExtra("sms_body", getText(R.id.editText1));
 startActivity(intent);

Comment: Thanks a lot issathink.. i got my string by mgActivity.putExtra("sms_body", getString(R.string.gm1));