# Send SMS to a specific contact

Tags: android

I created a button that when clicked shows us the list of phone contacts , I will wish to select a contact from the list and send him a message.

My application allows you to send a message by manually entering the number I want to link the contact selectednext via the "contact" button and sending SMS

Any ideas?

Edit : Here code for contact

```
@Override public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data){ super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(reqCode)
    {
        case (PICK_CONTACT):
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
                Uri contactData = data.getData();

                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst())
                {
                    String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                    String hasPhone =
                            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                    if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                    {
                        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,null, null);
                        phones.moveToFirst();
                        String cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

H

```
contact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BoutonContact);

        contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);


            }
        });
```

My send SMS method :

protected void envoiSMS() {
    Log.i("Envoyer SMS", "");

```
String phoneNum = txtPhoneNum.getText().toString();
String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();
try {
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNum, null, message, null, null);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS envoyé", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Echec à l'envoi du SMS veuillez réessayer", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: How are you storing your contacts? If they are stored as an object, simply add the phone number for the contact as a field within the object and then use that field whenever you send the text message after the user selects a specific contact.

Comment: I just do not know how to store the selectednext contact and subsequently used to send an SMS

Comment: Exactly like @issathink has suggested. Simply store the phone number in the object and then call, as per his example, the `getPhoneNumber` method which retrieves the number from the object and then pass it to your sms method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){

  ItemClicked item = adapter.getItem(position);

  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + item.getPhoneNumber()));

  intent.putExtra("sms_body", item.getMessageBody());
  startActivity(intent);

}
```

EDIT :

@Override public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data){ super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

```
switch(reqCode)
{
    case (PICK_CONTACT):
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            Uri contactData = data.getData();

            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst())
            {
                String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                String hasPhone =
                        c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                {
                    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,null, null);
                    phones.moveToFirst();
                    String cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + cNumber));
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, i've just add this code to MainActivity.java and that tells me " Cannot resolve symbol" ItemClicked

Comment: By "ItemClicked" i mean the type of object used by your ListView.

Comment: Just add the code @issathink has provided to your `onClick` method

Comment: Thanks and sorry guys.but when I add your edited code to methode onActivityResult that tell me Cannot resolve symbol item at line : Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("sms:" + item.getPhoneNumber())); I've to remplace it whith what ? edit : i've edited my first post to show you more

Comment: Sorry it was my fault, it should be ok now.

Comment: Thanks it's ok !! But that does not matter , I mean it: I want when I click on the contact that fills my EditText (where normally I have to manually fill in the number ) by the number of the contact selectednext

Comment: @issathink tu parle français ?

Comment: @Digger i don't know if we have right to speak french. oui je parle français.

Comment: No problem. J'ai répondu à une question similaire y a pas longtemps tu peux y jeter un coup d'oeil : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671131/button-click-textview-text-to-android-inbuilt-messaging-app/27671178?noredirect=1#comment43758079_27671178

Comment: D'accord merci,est - ce que tu m'ajouté ? je n'arrive pas à trouvé ton compte

Comment: Tu me suis pas donc je peux pas t'envoyer de messages.

Comment: C'est bon je t'ai envoyé un mail.